Apache websocket connection using daphne uploading django project
asg.py


import os

from django.urls import re_path

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
import django
from django.urls import path 

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mywebsite.settings')
os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true"

django.setup()

from video.consumers import VideoConsumers
from chat.consumers import Myconsumers


application = get_asgi_application()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http":application,
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                [
                path("ws/video_call/",VideoConsumers.as_asgi()),
                path('ws/ac/<str:uuid>/',Myconsumers.as_asgi())
                    
                ]
                
            )
        )
    ),

})

daphne.service file
  GNU nano 7.2                                                                 daphne.service                                                                           [Unit]
Description=Daphne ASGI Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/mywebsite

ExecStart=/var/www/mywebsite/venv/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 mywebsite.asgi:application

Restart=on-failure


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

dahpne.service is working proper
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.kartikprajapati.com
    ServerAdmin kartikprajapati26122004@gmail.com
    #Document Root is not required

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /static /var/www/mywebsite/static
    <Directory /var/www/mywebsite/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /media /var/www/mywebsite/media
    <Directory /var/www/mywebsite/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/mywebsite/mywebsite>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    

    ProxyPass "/ws/" "wss://kartikprajapati.com:8001/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/ws/" "wss://kartikprajapati.com:8001/"
   ProxyPassReverse "/ws/" "wss://kartikprajapati.com:8001/"

    WSGIDaemonProcess mywebsite python-home=/var/www/mywebsite/venv python-path=/var/www/mywebsite
    WSGIProcessGroup mywebsite
    WSGIScriptAlias /  /var/www/mywebsite/mywebsite/wsgi.py
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.kartikprajapati.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

my daphne is working on 8001 port with 0.0.0.0 IP means for all the IP
root@srv520922:~# systemctl status daphne
● daphne.service - Daphne ASGI Server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/daphne.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-05-08 15:42:10 IST; 40min ago
   Main PID: 30025 (daphne)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4658)
     Memory: 49.4M (peak: 49.6M)
        CPU: 1.197s
     CGroup: /system.slice/daphne.service
             └─30025 /var/www/mywebsite/venv/bin/python /var/www/mywebsite/venv/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 mywebsite>

May 08 15:42:10 srv520922 systemd[1]: Started daphne.service - Daphne ASGI Server.
May 08 15:42:11 srv520922 daphne[30025]: 2024-05-08 15:42:11,157 INFO     Starting server at tcp:port=8001:interface=0.>
May 08 15:42:11 srv520922 daphne[30025]: 2024-05-08 15:42:11,158 INFO     HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2>
May 08 15:42:11 srv520922 daphne[30025]: 2024-05-08 15:42:11,158 INFO     Configuring endpoint tcp:port=8001:interface=>
May 08 15:42:11 srv520922 daphne[30025]: 2024-05-08 15:42:11,159 INFO     Listening on TCP address 0.0.0.0:8001
lines 1-15/15 (END)

when ever I call wss://kartikprajapati.com/ws/video_call/ it is showing error please help
i have done
a2enmod proxy rewrite proxy_http proxy_wstunnel

error:-
[Wed May 08 16:01:15.693322 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 30048:tid 140661514831552] [remote 49.36.71.188:54708] Not Found: /ws/video_call/   websocket is not connecting
if you want any more information about my code and configuration pleasse comment
i have fixing it since 2  to 3 days please if you know any thing please help
I have done lot configuration but it did not helped i want to know that how step step process to config it because https is working but wss is not wokring

If you are trying to run this locally, then you need to remove the proxy to wss and use ws.
In order to run the application on the internet, we need to use wss with https, whereas your application uses http. Also, it seems you are using an asgi.py with and asgi application, but your apache code defines a wsgi application, that is not necessary. Using Daphne with Django Channels, we are using the asynchronous version, asgi.
Here is an Apache server configuration working with Daphne and Django Channels for websockets on a Ubuntu Linux server.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://127.0.0.1:8001%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
ProxyPass /wss/ wss://127.0.0.1:8001/
ProxyPassReverse /wss/ wss://127.0.0.1:8001/
...
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/ca_bundle.crt

It is recommended to run this command to run Daphne on a production level server, I included a command to run Daphne on a local server. At production level, you need a either a Kubernetes or Docker container to keep Daphne running.
daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 django_project.asgi:application // Local Development Level
daphne -e ssl:443:privateKey=key.pem:certKey=crt.pem django_project.asgi:application // Production Level

